# Implementing IValueConverter to get Name from ID

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a table column called LOCATION_ID. I want to show the LOCATION_NAME which is located in the LOCATION table instead of the ID.

I am trying to implement IValueConverter but can't figure out how to do it. I am using WPF with entity framework.

How would I pass the ID value to this converter?

I have a method name GetLocationNameByID(). Where in the converter would I Call this method? And how would I bind the return value to the datagrid XAML?

Comment: If you're using EF, why not join on your `Location` table and pull back the `location_name`? Then you'd be able to bind to `Entity.Location.LocationName`, or something to that effect.

Comment: For that do I need to use WCF? I am not currenty using WCF

Comment: Only if you need to pull back a `Location` through a Web Service (I don't think you do). If it is all in your DB, EF is all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing the `IValueConverer` interface is pretty straightforward.  In the XAML, you'd have something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="CarSystem.CustomControls.AlarmDisplayer"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
        DataContext="{Binding Path=MyDataContextObject, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyIValueConverter x:Key="Converter" />
</Window.Resoures>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Converter} Path=MyProperty}" />

</Window>
```

When WPF detects a change in the value of the `MyProperty` in the `MyDataContextObject`, it calls the `MyIValueConverter` object's `Convert` method, passing the value of the property as the `Value` parameter.  Your implementation of the `Convert` method does what it has to do & returns the string to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use multi-binding, have your value converter implement the IMultiValueConverter interface. The converter takes an object array, each of which can be a binding to your XAML.

```
<TextBox>  
   <TextBox.Text>  
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">  
          <MultiBinding.Bindings>  
             <Binding Path="SomeProperty" />  
             <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>  
          </MultiBinding.Bindings>  
       </MultiBinding>  
   </TextBox.Text>  
</TextBox>
```